# Readonly struct vs classes

Tags: c#, .net

Assuming you only have immutable types
and you have all your code up to date to C# 7.3 and your methods are using the `in` keyword for inputs

Why would you ever use a class instead of a readonly struct?

The downside of using structs was that copying was expensive, but assuming you prevent any copy (defensive compiler copy or expressed by code), readonly structs allow you to only copy the reference (as classes do) and avoid heap allocation and pressure on the garbage collector.

Excluding special cases (which I guess it could be a very large object that won't fit on the stack) would you use readonly struct as first choice normally?

The case I am interested in is where they are used as data containers.

Comment: Because you want to access and edit the same object by reference?

Comment: Pick `struct` or `class`, first and foremost based on whether you want *value* semantics or *reference* semantics.

Comment: Also no inheritance.

Comment: You've taken limited range of use-cases, and tried to ask generic question, based on them. Reference types are not data containers only.

Comment: @MineR object will be immutable so access will be by ref because of the `in` keyword and there won't be any edit. Good point about inheritance.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you explain what you mean? the struct will be still passed by reference.

Comment: @Dennis I'll update the question and specify I mean using them as data containers

Comment: structs should represent *values*. All instances of a struct with the same field values are the "same" and interchangeable (e.g. all `5`s are the same). classes represent *objects*. They have an inherent "identity" to them that isn't part of their contained data. Even when you have two instances with the same data, they're not "the same" for at least some ways of considering them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever note that there's some exceptions though, for example `string` acts more like a struct in your example but it's a class.

Comment: @jrh - yep, they will behave that way in a lot of ways. I can still pick 'em apart with good old `ReferenceEquals` though :-)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

structs should not be looked on as "cheap objects"; they have similar feature sets that are overlapping in some areas and disjoint in others. For example:

- structs can't participate in polymorphism
- you can't treat a struct as an instance of an interface without boxing it (caveat: "constrained call", but that only works in some scenarios)
- a lot of library APIs *won't work well* (or possibly at all) with structs - they expect mutable POCOs; you'll *probably* want to use a library to get data from a database, serialize it, or render it in a UI - all of these things choke a bit with structs
- structs don't work well with some patterns, such as tree or sibling relationships (a `Foo` can't contain a `Foo` if it is a struct) - there are others
- structs, and immutable types generally, can be awkward to work with

Also, note that until very recently ("ref returns" and "ref locals") it was very hard to achieve some parts of "readonly structs allow you to only copy the reference"; this is now much simpler.

But frankly, in most scenarios POCOs are *just easier to work with*, and are fine for most application-code scenarios.

There are certainly times when structs are an amazing choice. It just isn't *every time*. I *would* however, support the notion that if you're going to use a `struct`, it should be either a `readonly struct` (by default) or a `ref struct` (if you know why you're doing it); mutable non-`ref` structs are a recipe for pain.

Comment: All valid points, thanks. Should I have to pick in a case where none of this apply would you suggest blindly going with readonly structs as default choice then? What are the cases you mentioned that make them hard to work with aside your points above?

Comment: @user4388177 the reality that data often needs to change during your code is a big one :) especially when the data is in something like a `List<T>`, which doesn't have a "ref return" API (and cannot sensibly do so, because if somebody calls `Add` and forces the underlying array to grow, folks would expect the `ref` to point to the *active* array, but existing `ref`s would actually be interior pointers into the *old* array). This means you can't just do `myRef = myRef.WithSomeChangedProperty("foo");` (to overwrite the value)

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm more and more moving towards a more functional/immutable approach to the design. When I have to create a type and I want to enforce its immutability I believe readonly struct could be a good fit. Lists and arrays (even if you use immutable versions) most of the time fall into the "big objects" category so I wouldn't dream of using structs there.

Comment: @user4388177 for lists, though - if GC is your concern, you *might* want to consider pools [see here for context](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31492) (look for "Here's the gist" for the actual code uesd)

Comment: Yep, we use ArrayPool, really useful. Thanks. I didn't know there was a GitHub issue about list pools, interesting. Although we ended up with some bugs in production with data from previous iterations XD.

Comment: @user4388177 yeah, you need to be *really* careful not to read past what you've written; in this case, the list implementation takes care of that